# Where Can I Find Views and codes of Login and register pages Created by Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-identity

I Have just created an asp.net core mvc project with Identity support using Visual studio 2019. There Are built in Login/Register Pages . but i cant find Their Source code and cshtml!
It Uses Areas but i searched All Possible Places From this article in documentation
[Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0#area-folder-structure)

I need to customize Login/Register Views and Their Functionality. Where Can I Find Them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that ASP.NET Core provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a RCL.

To modify the code/view(s) and change the default behavior, you can refer to the following doc to  apply the scaffolder to selectively add the source code contained in the Identity RCL, then you can customize the generated code based on your actual requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio